Setting up an IntelliJ, Java/Maven and Cucumber, Selenium project
I've been spending hours with ChatGPT trying to get this to run, but I'm running into the same errors again and again.
My project is a fresh, simple java/kotlin project, with Selenium and Cucumber. (Maven.) I'm trying just to get a simple test (feature file and step definition to run), without luck.
Here's my project setup:
project

cucumber (module)


src






main










java (nothing here, as I'm using "test" instead of "main")












resources (nothing here, as I'm using "test" instead of "main")










test








java










e2e














setup


















Hooks.kt




















RunCucumberTest


















testdefinitions


















TestStepDefinitions.kt














resources










features














testfeature.feature









Hooks.kt:
package e2e.setup

import io.cucumber.java.After
import io.cucumber.java.Before
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager

class Hooks {

    companion object {
        lateinit var driver: WebDriver
    }

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup()
        driver = ChromeDriver()
        driver.manage().window().maximize()
    }

    @After
    fun tearDown() {
        driver.quit()
    }
}

RunCucumberTest.kt:
package e2e.setup

import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions
import org.junit.runner.RunWith

@RunWith(Cucumber::class)
@CucumberOptions(
    features = ["src/test/resources/features"],
    glue = ["e2e.testdefinitions"],
    plugin = ["pretty", "html:target/cucumber-reports"]
)
class RunCucumberTest

TestStepDefinitions.kt:
package e2e.testdefinitions

import io.cucumber.java.en.Given
import io.cucumber.java.en.Then
import io.cucumber.java.en.When
import e2e.setup.Hooks
import org.openqa.selenium.By
import org.junit.Assert.assertTrue

class StepDefinitions {

    @Given("I open the browser and go to the Google homepage")
    fun i_open_the_browser_and_go_to_the_google_homepage() {
        Hooks.driver.get("https://www.google.com")
    }

    @When("I search for {string}")
    fun i_search_for(searchQuery: String) {
        Hooks.driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys(searchQuery)
        Hooks.driver.findElement(By.name("q")).submit()
    }

    @Then("the page title should start with {string}")
    fun the_page_title_should_start_with(titleStartsWith: String) {
        assertTrue(Hooks.driver.title.startsWith(titleStartsWith))
    }
}

testfeature.feature:
Feature: Google Search

Scenario: Searching on Google
    Given I open the browser and go to the Google homepage
    When I search for "Selenium WebDriver"
    Then the page title should start with "Selenium WebDriver"

The project builds fine, and the libraries and dependencies all seem to be right.
But when I try running the scenario in the feature file, I get this error:
Before All/After All failed
io.cucumber.core.backend.CucumberBackendException: Please annotate a glue class with some context configuration.

For example:

   @CucumberContextConfiguration
   @SpringBootTest(classes = TestConfig.class)
   public class CucumberSpringConfiguration { }
Or: 

   @CucumberContextConfiguration
   @ContextConfiguration( ... )
   public class CucumberSpringConfiguration { }
    at io.cucumber.spring.SpringFactory.start(SpringFactory.java:102)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.Runner.buildBackendWorlds(Runner.java:134)

The examples doesn't tell me much, since I'm not well versed with Spring.
But as far as I can see, my glue and features specifications are correct? But obviously not, or not according to IntelliJ.

Do you actually want to use Spring with Cucumber or did that get added to your dependencies because the confabulation engine said so?

Basically, yes. I don't think I need it. But I need some way to set up the test environment.

You may want to use https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/cucumber-picocontainer instead. It only facilitates very simple constructor dependency injection and nothing else (so wrap your WebDriver, and inject the wrapper, don't inject the WebDriver). Otherwise you'll have to read https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/cucumber-spring and see if that helps you getting started.

That's all well and good, but that's a comepletely new project. I have a project I've created from a project template, with the necessary setup for my domain. So it's THIS project I need to get Cucumber and Selenium working in.
